When Click on 'GetNewAccessToken' then it shows blank screen in Postman
I'm facing an issue in Postman: whenever I click on "Get New Access Token," it redirects me to a blank screen instead of initiating the token generation process. Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I want to generate a new access token in Postman

I had the same issue because I was using an SSL certificate in my browser that wasn't working anymore. Usually I just click it away and choose to sign on using my email and password but Postman chooses to instantly select the SSL certificate if it can find one. If the certificate is wrong it just redirects you to a blank page.
Only found out it was because of the SSL certificate after looking at the network tab and reading the faulty request that it had made.
